# Floating point computer - Trouble with getting back correct results

Tags: floating-point, theory

Having trouble with a challenge.

Let's say I have a theoretical, **base 10**, floating point calculator with the following characteristics

- Only 3 digits for mantissa
- 1 digit for exponent
- Sign for mantissa and exponent

How would this machine compute the following?

`300 + \sum_{i=1}^{100} 0.2`

The correct result is 320. The machine's result is 300. But why? Can't get where the 20 goes goes missing...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notwithstanding davin's answer, the number 0.2 is not 0: 2e-1 is representable in your system. What's happening here is that 300.2 is not representable to full precision, so 300 + 0.2 gets rounded down to 300. If you do this 100 times, you still end up with 300 :-)

Your system should be able to compute 300 + 100*0.2 correctly, however.

Comment: how do you represent 2e-1 with 1 digit in the exponent? in fact, come to think of it, how do you represent 300 with 1 digit in the exponent?

Comment: @davin: One signed decimal digit.

Comment: hmmm, must have missed the sign digit for the exponent, although even so, representing 300?

Comment: @davin: 300 = 3e2. What's the problem?

Comment: @TonyK, with 1 bit how do you represent the exponent 2, you need 2 bits!?!

Comment: @davin: *sigh* 1 DECIMAL DIGIT

Answer (score 1):

The number 0.2 in this calculator is 0, because it should evaluate to 2 x 10^(-1), although the exponent has only 1 digit, which allows a range of 0 and 1, so -1 is outside its range. The underflow results in a truncation, which produces 0.

So if we sum 0 one hundred times and add the result to 300, we get 300.

Comment: Although to be honest, there are a lot of arbitrary things there that dont always occur. The handling of underflow is arbitrary. Moreover, having 1 digit in a binary system is problematic, because 1 ends up being its own two's complement etc. so the scenario as is is a little silly.

Comment: @Francisco P. my answer assumed the representation was base 10, do you disagree with my reasoning?

Comment: "although the exponent has only 1 digit, which allows a range of 0 and 1" this led me to believe you were talking about base 2.